# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, on second button press

Tags: node.js, express, flutter, dart

I'm currently learning Flutter/DART and I'm trying to build app that communicates with the server but I have problems. There is a Sign-In button that sends request to the server, server checks if there is user with that username and password and response gets sent back. Everything is working like charm for the first button press, but if button is pressed for the second time and so on error pop ups on server:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\server.js:14:39)
    at Function.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\db.js:17:20)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Flutter Node.js Login-Register App\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Here is the code from flutter app and from node.js server:

Flutter:
Function gets called on button press:

```
void signIn(username, password) async {
    final bodyEncoded = jsonEncode(
      {
        'username': model.username,
        'password': model.password,
      },
    );

    final response = await http.post(
      'http://192.168.0.110:3000/signin',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: bodyEncoded,
    );

    if (response.body == 'true')
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MainBody(),
        ),
      );
    else
      setState(() => {elementOpacity = 1.0});
  }
```

Server

*server.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('./server.json');

exports.app = app;
const db = require('./db');

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    app.emit('signInRequest', username, password);

    app.on('response', (value) => res.send(value));
});

app.listen(server.port, () => console.log('Server running on port ' + server.port));
```

*db.js*

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionUri = require('./db.json');
const db = mysql.createConnection(connectionUri);
const app = require('./server').app;

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    console.log('MySQL connection successful!');
});

app.on('signInRequest', (username, password) => {
    db.query("SELECT Count(*) AS 'count' FROM Users WHERE (Username = '" + username + "' AND Password = '" + password + "')", (err, result) => {
        if(err)
            throw err;

        return app.emit('response', result[0].count == 1 ? true : false);
    });
});
```

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Answer as an answer, but as a direct comment on your code: never, _ever_, write database queries this way. https://xkcd.com/327/ is funny because it's true, so read https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries and put that into practice.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply, I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rely on events, but you don't tie those events to specific request, you're going to have a bad time: right now, requests map to "nothing", but then the code goes on to tie the event that triggers a response to *every `app.on("response", ...)` binding that you ever declared*... and in the process, also preventing responses from ever getting garbage collected because they keep needing to stick around for event handling. So your code also has what is effectively a memory leak.

Instead of doing this with events, use promises/`async` functions and then `await` their return value. That way one request maps to one response, and things get cleaned up properly too.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const database = require('./database.js');
const server = require('./server.json');

exports.app = app;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/signin', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    if (!validateUsernameAndPassword(username, password)) {
      // Remember to write a global error handler. Or don't use
      // Express' next(err) functionality but respond with a call-appropriate
      // response that has the correct HTTP error code, too.
      next(new Error("you better believe this should be an error"));
    }
    const value = await database.handleSignInRequest(username, password);
    res.send(value);
});

app.listen(server.port, () => console.log('Server running on port ' + server.port));
```

database.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionUri = require('./db.json');
const db = mysql.createConnection(connectionUri);

// the db code shouldn't have to know anything about express or express apps

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    console.log('MySQL connection successful!');
});

function handleSignInRequest(username, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Now, a super important note: NEVER QUERY A DATABASE DIRECTLY LIKE THIS:

    db.query(`SELECT Count(*) AS 'count' FROM Users WHERE (Username = '${username}' AND Password = '${password}')`, (err, result) => {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        resolve(result[0].count == 1 ? true : false);
    });

    // Look up how to query your database in a sanitized, prepared statement
    // fashion. https://xkcd.com/327/ is a word famous piece of satire for
    // good reason.
    //
    // Please read https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries and
    // put that into practice.
  });
});

module.exports = { handleSignInRequest };
```